# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (1, 4) but got array with shape (1, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm fairly new to RL and i can't really understand why I'm getting this error.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory



def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,states)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
                  nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

def main():

    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
    states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
    actions = env.action_space.n
    #print(env.reset())
    #print(env.action_space.sample())
    print(env.observation())

    model = build_model(states, actions)


    dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
    dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),metrics=['mae'])
    dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)


main()
```

I can't understand why it's getting an array with shape (1,2). I've looked through some people's similar questions but I can't apply it to mine.
It starts the training but it fails immediately with 0 steps performed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means you are passing data with shape (1, 2) to the model. What is the shape of `env`?

Comment: @Djinn I'm not sure if this is it but : env.observation_space.shape and env.action_space.n returns (4,) and 2 respectively.

Comment: No, not the objects within, the object `env`, what is its shape.

Comment: Also, can you include the whole code including the include section. The code seems to be trimmed at the top.

Comment: @Bhupen I've added the entire code now!

Comment: @Djinn I'm sorry, i'm new to RL can you tell me how i'm able to see env's shape?

Comment: `env.shape`, or if it's a tensor, `tf.shape()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'CartPoleEnv' object has no attribute 'shape'. But from what I've google'd: action is a `ndarray` with shape `(1,)` and observation is a `ndarray` with shape `(4,)`.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `dqn.summary`

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're trying to flatten a 1D array? You could probably just remove the flatten layer and continue without any issues. Your input arrays are already "flattened" in the most fundamental sense.

Comment: I cannot use summary on dqn, however I can do dqn.get_config and (among other info) i get this: 'batch_input_shape': (None, 1, 4).

Comment: Also, I understand that the Flatten line doesn't make sense but if i remove it i get this error: ```'Sequential' object has no attribute '_nested_outputs'```. I ended up removing the line and adding this in the main function ```model.build(input_shape=(1,states))```and I'm able show the model's summary but the error shows up anyways. @Djinn

Comment: The error is probably coming from `env` not being a dataset, but treated as an array of two elements. Pass the specific contents of `env` to `x` and `y` in `.fit()`.

Answer (score 1):

The keras-rl2 library has been discontinued since 2021. See their github repo here: https://github.com/taylormcnally/keras-rl2 You can see it has been archived and no longer being updated.

They have also deleted their online documentation.

Gym recommends that you do not use keras-rl2, rather use other libraries such as https://github.com/google/dopamine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It seems that the issue is due to the compatibility between gym and keras-rl. Basically gym wants the reset method to return a tuple of the observation and the info dictionary. But keras-rl assumes that the reset method only returns the observation. I had to fork the keras-rl library and change the `observation = env.reset()` calls to `observation, info = env.reset()`. I had to do something similar for `env.step()` since keras-rl thinks it returns a tuple of size 4, when gym wants it to be of size 5 with two booleans.

Answer (score 1):

So I got it Working this way,First of all, go Inside the **core.py** file.Then,

1. Initialise the value of first_time in the **init**(self) of the Agent class

`self.first_time = True`

2. In my case im updating the fit(), so go to the fit() and replace

`action = self.forward(observation)`

with

```
if self.first_time:
    action = self.forward(observation[0])
    self.first_time = False
else:
    action = self.forward(observation)
```

3. Inside the while loop we were working in, under

if observation is None:

set the value of first_time as True

```
if observation is None:  # start of a new episode
    self.first_time = True
```

4. Inside the same loop, if u go a bit down u can see

observation, r, done, info = env.step(action)

Replace it with,

```
observation, r, done,trunc, info = env.step(action)
```

And that did the job for me. hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

although it has been discontinued, I fixed it by editing the core.py
I changed the

`action = self.forward(observation)`

to

```
            if first_time:
                action = self.forward(observation[0])
                first_time = False
            else:
                action = self.forward(observation)
```

and its fine now :) nake sure you init the first_time=True at the top of the method

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same problem and faced the exact same issue. Installing the package 'rl-agents==0.1.1' solved the issue for me. Thanks

Here is a link to my repo for this project
https://github.com/tahmiid/DQNCartPoleAI

Answer (score 0):

I use gym.Wrapper to change the output of env.reset and env.step, like this:

```
class GymWrapper(gym.Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        gym.Wrapper.__init__(self, env)
        self.env = env

    def reset(self, **kwargs):
        obs, _ = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
        return obs

    def step(self, action):
        obs, reward, done, info, _ = self.env.step(action)
        return obs, reward, done, {}

env = GymWrapper(gym.make(ENV_NAME))
```

it works