# Deep Q network trained successfully but test is not working

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am using a DQN agent to solve cartpole problem from openAI gym. The agent is trained successfully but the test method showing following error.

```
scores *=* dqn.test(env, nb_episodes\*=*100, visualize*=\*False)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 1
----> 1 scores = dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=100, visualize=False)
      2 print(np.mean(scores.history['episode_reward']))

File ~/miniconda3/envs/qenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rl/core.py:347, in Agent.test(self, env, nb_episodes, action_repetition, callbacks, visualize, nb_max_episode_steps, nb_max_start_steps, start_step_policy, verbose)
    344 while not done:
    345     callbacks.on_step_begin(episode_step)
--> 347     action = self.forward(observation)
    348     if self.processor is not None:
    349         action = self.processor.process_action(action)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/qenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py:224, in DQNAgent.forward(self, observation)
    221 def forward(self, observation):
    222     # Select an action.
    223     state = self.memory.get_recent_state(observation)
--> 224     q_values = self.compute_q_values(state)
    225     if self.training:
    226         action = self.policy.select_action(q_values=q_values)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/qenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py:68, in AbstractDQNAgent.compute_q_values(self, state)
     67 def compute_q_values(self, state):
---> 68     q_values = self.compute_batch_q_values([state]).flatten()
     69     assert q_values.shape == (self.nb_actions,)
     70     return q_values

File ~/miniconda3/envs/qenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py:63, in AbstractDQNAgent.compute_batch_q_values(self, state_batch)
     61 def compute_batch_q_values(self, state_batch):
     62     batch = self.process_state_batch(state_batch)
---> 63     q_values = self.model.predict_on_batch(batch)
     64     assert q_values.shape == (len(state_batch), self.nb_actions)
     65     return q_values

File ~/miniconda3/envs/qenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training_v1.py:1305, in Model.predict_on_batch(self, x)
   1300     raise NotImplementedError(
   1301         "`predict_on_batch` is not supported for models distributed "
   1302         "with tf.distribute.Strategy."
   1303     )
   1304 # Validate and standardize user data.
-> 1305 inputs, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(
   1306     x, extract_tensors_from_dataset=True
   1307 )
   1308 # If `self._distribution_strategy` is True, then we are in a replica
   1309 # context at this point.
   1310 if self.run_eagerly or self._distribution_strategy:

File ~/miniconda3/envs/qenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training_v1.py:2652, in Model._standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle, extract_tensors_from_dataset)
   2643 if (
   2644     not run_eagerly
   2645     and is_build_called
   (...)
   2648     and any(_is_symbolic_tensor(v) for v in all_inputs)
   2649 ):
   2650     return [], [], None
-> 2652 return self._standardize_tensors(
   2653     x,
   2654     y,
   2655     sample_weight,
   2656     run_eagerly=run_eagerly,
   2657     dict_inputs=dict_inputs,
   2658     is_dataset=is_dataset,
   2659     class_weight=class_weight,
   2660     batch_size=batch_size,
   2661 )

File ~/miniconda3/envs/qenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training_v1.py:2693, in Model._standardize_tensors(self, x, y, sample_weight, run_eagerly, dict_inputs, is_dataset, class_weight, batch_size)
   2690 # Standardize the inputs.
   2691 if not isinstance(x, (tf.compat.v1.data.Dataset, tf.data.Dataset)):
   2692     # TODO(fchollet): run static checks with dataset output shape(s).
-> 2693     x = training_utils_v1.standardize_input_data(
   2694         x,
   2695         feed_input_names,
   2696         feed_input_shapes,
   2697         check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
   2698         exception_prefix="input",
   2699     )
   2701 # Get typespecs for the input data and sanitize it if necessary.
   2702 # TODO(momernick): This should be capable of doing full input validation
   2703 # at all times - validate that this is so and refactor the
   2704 # standardization code.
   2705 if isinstance(x, tf.data.Dataset):

File ~/miniconda3/envs/qenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training_utils_v1.py:731, in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    725             for dim, ref_dim in zip(data_shape, shape):
    726                 if (
    727                     ref_dim != dim
    728                     and ref_dim is not None
    729                     and dim is not None
    730                 ):
--> 731                     raise ValueError(
                            "Error when checking "
    733                         + exception_prefix
    734                         + ": expected "
    735                         + names[i]
    736                         + " to have shape "
    737                         + str(shape)
    738                         + " but got array with shape "
    739                         + str(data_shape)
    740                     )
    741 return data

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have shape (1, 4) but got array with shape (1, 2)
```

My NN architecture:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 4)                 0         
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 24)                120       
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 24)                600       
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 50        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 770 (3.01 KB)
Trainable params: 770 (3.01 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

I have modified the core.py according to this: [ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (1, 4) but got array with shape (1, 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73978651/valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-flatten-input-to-have-shape-1)
This solves the training problem of the agent but the same error that I got while training arises when testing of the agent is done as shown above.